Azure databricks Pyspark.ml issue constructor public org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder(java.lang.String) is not whitelisted
I'm running RandomForest on Azure Databricks using pyspark.ml.
Error Message:
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder. Trace: py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Constructor public org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder(java.lang.String) is not whitelisted.

Runtime: 14.3.x-scala2.12
Policy: Shared Compute
Access Mode: Shared
Instance: Standard_D4ads_v5
Its working fine with Databricks Personal Compute, but issue in Shared Compute. I want to use Shared Compute only bcoz in Personal compute I'm facing different issue like (Column is not iterable.)
Is there any workaround?

Can you try the `configspark.databricks.pyspark.enablePy4JSecurity false config and see if you can disable the crendetail pass through for your shared cluster.


ERROR : Py4JError: An error occurred while calling
None.org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder. Trace:
py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Constructor public
org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder(java.lang.String) is not
whitelisted.

This issue is caused by a specific combination of cluster mode or access mode (Like High Concurrency, Shared, Single User, etc.) along with the Credential Passthrough settings.
Since the ERROR is related to Py4J security restrictions, which can limit access to some classes in the shared environment.
I have tried the below configspark.databricks.pyspark.enablePy4JSecurity false
spark.databricks.pyspark.enableProcessIsolation false

ERROR details:
spark.databricks.pyspark.enableProcessIsolation is only allowed when the security mode is Custom or None.




Since you are able to use the RandomForest in Personal Compute as workaround I have tried the below approach using the spark.databricks.pyspark.enableProcessIsolation false
In spark config using the NO ISOLATION SHARED cluster.
The above config works fine for RandomForest
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

Results:

+---+--------+-----+-----+----------+
| id|category|value|label|prediction|
+---+--------+-----+-----+----------+
|  0|       A|   10|  0.0|       0.0|
|  1|       B|   20|  1.0|       1.0|
|  2|       A|   30|  0.0|       0.0|
|  3|       C|   40|  1.0|       1.0|
|  4|       B|   50|  0.0|       0.0|
+---+--------+-----+-----+----------+


know more about py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: … is not whitelisted
Shared access mode limitations on Unity Catalog

Thanks for the help, when I change to Access mode No isolation shared, then its returning [NOT_ITERABLE] Column is not iterable error. Same code is working fine in Shared Access mode,

this seems to a limitation with the Shared Compute. you can use the single user cluster in this scenario.
